# Directionality in JPQL joins for Spring Boot JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Spring Boot here. I have the following two JPA entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "accounts")
public class Account {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "account_id")
  private Long id;

  // lots of stuff

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE])
  @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id", referencedColumnName = "profile_id")
  private Profile profile;    // CAN be null

  // Getters, setters & ctors
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "profiles")
public class Profile {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "account_id")
  private Long id;

  // doesn't really matter lots of stuff in here

  // Getters, setters & ctors
}
```

It is possible for some Accounts to have Profiles, and some will not (their Profiles will be null). I would like to create a `CrudRepository` impl that essentially does this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM profiles p
INNER JOIN accounts a
WHERE a.profile_id = null
```

Essentially, get me all the Profiles that are "orphaned" and are associated with any accounts here.

I'm confused as to whether I need an `CrudRepository<Long,Account>` impl or a `CrudRepository<Long,Profile>` impl and on what that impl would look like. My best pseudo-attempt thus far looks like:

```
public interface ProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<Profile, Long> {
    @Query("FROM Account act WHERE act.profile = null")
    public Set<Profile> findOrphanedProfiles();
}
```

Can anyone help fill in the gaps for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, JPQL NULL check syntax is `IS NULL`, not `== NULL` (see [JPQL docs](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/comparison) - the link is for ObjectWeb, but applies to any JPA implementation)

Second, if you want to check for orphaned records, you definitely **don't** want to join in the table they're orphaned from.

Your last attempt at it,

```
public interface ProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<Profile, Long> {
    @Query("FROM Account act WHERE act.profile = null")
    public Set<Profile> findOrphanedProfiles();
}
```

was actually pretty close, just replace `== null` with `is null` and you should be all set.

EDIT: if you're looking for profiles that don't have accounts associated with them, `EXISTS` query is what you're looking for:

```
public interface ProfileRepository extends CrudRepository<Profile, Long> {
    @Query("FROM Profile p WHERE NOT EXISTS (FROM Account a WHERE a.profile = p)")
    public Set<Profile> findDisassociatedProfiles();
}
```

EDIT: if your `Profile`s maintain a list of associated accounts as a property (it's not included in the code you posted, but maybe it was omitted), you can query for disassociated profiles even shorter:

`FROM Profile p WHERE p.accounts IS EMPTY`

Comment: Thanks @Alex (+1) but wouldn't that fetch a `Set<Account>` (all the Accounts with null profiles)? I'm looking to just get a `Set<Profile>` that I know aren't associated with any Accounts...

Comment: @smeeb Since your accounts point to profiles and not the other way around, it's accounts that can be orphaned and not profiles. Or are you actually looking for profiles that don't have any accounts pointing to them? The question semantics must have confused me a bit, as this isn't what "orphaned" usually means. I'll include the query for this scenario as well in my answer

Comment: Thanks @Alex I'll give it a try. Per "orphaning", correct me if I'm wrong here but an "orphan" is a child without a parent. Since Accounts can *have A* Profile, I view them as the parents and Profiles as the children. Hence if a Profile doesn't have an Account (parent), its an "orphan". No?

Comment: @smeeb Generally, it is expected that parent is the "one" side of the relationship, and child is the "many" side. You can, of course, reverse the meanings, or even adopt a different naming convention altogether, but it will be counter-intuitive to understand. Note that, in case of a many-to-many relationship, either side can become "orphaned".